# JMeter: "Object moved to <a href="/aurl/Login.aspx">here" as Response Code

Tags: object, testing, load, jmeter, response

I am load testing for Login/Logout feature implemented in ASP.NET. When a number of users are increased, it starts showing response code as following after one of the user logout:

```html
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/aurl/Login.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you able to login successfully, you can ignore Object Moved response. If you are facing any error, make sure that you are handling session appropriately.